# What are the molecular mechanisms that make the turtle brain more resistant to hypoxia?

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, cellular-respiration

I know that turtle brains, particularly those of individual species that hibernate and burrow are particularly resilient to hypoxia and any tissue damage secondary to a hypoxic event.

What are the known molecular mechanisms behind this resiliency?  Does it have to do with the ability of their blood to store/release oxygen over extended periods, or is it molecular factors in the neural tissue that protect it from insult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bunch of literature on the topic. A good starting point is probably a short description with lots of references in [this thesis](http://indigo.lib.uic.edu/bitstream/handle/10027/8659/Peterson_Bethany.pdf?sequence=1) (page 8), not to talk about other articles, which pop up in [google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=turtle%20brain%20more%20resistant%20hypoxia&oi=scholart): [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2952077/), [2](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-5562-5_2).

The mechanisms are multifaceted and involve principally decrease in oxygen and ATP demands: reduced neuronal activity, lower density of ion channels (but hyper-polarization of the membranes) and so on. [Concerning blood flow](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-5562-5_2): "Brain blood flow was continued or increased, and oxygen and creatine phosphate (PCr) stores offered some immediate protection. As PCr declined, turtle brain became increasingly reliant upon anaerobic glycolysis."